# Resharper todo items wrong color

Tags: resharper

I have `Resharper` set to show `Bug` and `Not Implemented` as red in the todo list, and `Todo` as blue. Yet for some reason it doesn't seem to want to actually use those colors. Instead of red it uses orange, and instead of blue it uses pink...

[image]

Has anyone else ever dealt with this before?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, colors are configured for light color scheme. For dark scheme, like your's, ReSharper tries to adapt colors to be visible in any circumstances...